# Plex server won’t start

Tags: server, plex

I’ve been trying to set up a home Plex media server for fun but I’m getting this instead

```
sudo systemctl status plexmediaserver

× plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Sun 2023-12-24 14:34:32 CST; 41min ago
    Process: 3439 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/mkdir -p "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3441 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c  export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_INFO_VENDOR="$(grep ^NAME= /etc/os-release | awk -F= "{print \$2}" | tr -d \" )";  export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_INFO_MODEL="$(uname -m)";  export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_INFO_PLATFORM_>
   Main PID: 3441 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
        CPU: 167ms

Dec 24 14:34:32 Server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Dec 24 14:34:32 Server systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server.
Dec 24 14:34:32 Server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 24 14:34:32 Server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Dec 24 14:34:32 Server systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server.
```

Comment: It's usually best to provide software stack details; ie. what Ubuntu product & release are you using? ie. Ubuntu Core 22? Ubuntu Desktop 23.10?, Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS or what?  Did the *core dump* or crash file provide any clues?  or other system logs?  (*on your unstated system*)